# How to align text exactly beside the check mark svg image so as to use it as pros and cons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, svg

I am getting text below SVG image but I want to move it next to the SVG image so as it can be used as pros and cons section like this:-

Results I get-

[Text below svg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVNYB.png)

Results I want-

[text beside svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFFwo.png)

This the code:-
**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <style>
    .path {stroke-dasharray: 0 !important;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
  <polyline class="path check" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="100.2,40.2 51.5,88.8 29.8,67.5 "/>
</svg>
<p class="success">Oh Yeah!</p>
</head>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
svg {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  &.circle {
    -webkit-animation: dash .9s ease-in-out;
    animation: dash .9s ease-in-out;
  }
  &.line {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    -webkit-animation: dash .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: dash .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
  }
  &.check {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
    -webkit-animation: dash-check .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: dash-check .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
  }
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 60px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  &.success {
    color: #73AF55;
  }
  &.error {
    color: #D06079;
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash-check {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
}

@keyframes dash-check {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
}
</style>
```

***NOTE***
Please note that the animation duration is unlimited means always looping.
Paste the code in codepen editor to edit.
Please minify the code as per possible

Comment: Please, add a working example. This uses SCSS which won't work if not transpiled. Transpile it to normal CSS.

Comment: @Jorge Fuentes González dear sir plz remove the head style and HTML tags and paste into the codepn editor to code

Comment: @GoGoris Please tell how to make the text beside svg image

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the two elements in `<div></div>` and using css give `display : inline-block` to there child elements.

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  &.circle {
    -webkit-animation: dash .9s ease-in-out;
    animation: dash .9s ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  &.line {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    -webkit-animation: dash .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: dash .9s .35s ease-in-out
      forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  &.check {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
    -webkit-animation: dash-check .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: dash-check .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 60px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  &.success {
    color: #73AF55;
  }
  &.error {
    color: #D06079;
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash-check {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
}

@keyframes dash-check {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
}


.success_message{
  display: inline-block !important;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;    
}

.success_icon{
  display: inline-block !important;
  margin:0px !important;
}

.success_container{
  text-align : center;  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <style>
    .path {stroke-dasharray: 0 !important;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="success_container">
    <svg class="success_icon" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
    <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
    <polyline class="path check" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="100.2,40.2 51.5,88.8 29.8,67.5 "/>
  </svg>
  <p class="success_message">Oh Yeah!</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear sir plz make this ab=nimation continuous loop plz

Comment: @Aritra I have updated my answer. Animation duration is infinite.You can assign any value in the css for property :  animation-iteration-count

Comment: can you take it outside the `<head>`?

Answer (score 0):

Your text is shown under the image because you use `display: block;` on your svg and your text is a p-tag, which has `display: block` by default.

To show your text next to the image, both should have `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` or you should use other methods like a flexbox. The simplest fix would be to change your css for svg to `display: inline-block;` and change the p-tag with the button name to span, which is meant for inline text.

Answer (score 0):

remove margin form svg and p and add display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle; in both

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  &.circle {
    -webkit-animation: dash .9s ease-in-out;
    animation: dash .9s ease-in-out;
  }
  &.line {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    -webkit-animation: dash .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: dash .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
  }
  &.check {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
    -webkit-animation: dash-check .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: dash-check .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
  }
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  &.success {
    color: #73AF55;
  }
  &.error {
    color: #D06079;
  }
}

svg,p {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash-check {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
}

@keyframes dash-check {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <style>
    .path {stroke-dasharray: 0 !important;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
  <polyline class="path check" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="100.2,40.2 51.5,88.8 29.8,67.5 "/>
</svg>
<p class="success">Oh Yeah!</p>
</head>
</html>
```